# Unknown Syntax Error for Groovy File

Tags: angularjs, grails

I'm working on a site with CRUD capabilities for a school project. We're using angular, JSON groovy and MySql for the project. I'm using this code in an HTML file:

```
$scope.getUsers=function(){

    $scope.employees=$http.get('getUsers.groovy').success(function(response){
        return response.data
    }
```

When I run the html page and call the getUser function, I get this error:

> syntax error     getUsers.groovy:1

The code in the groovy file seems correct:

```
 import groovy.sql.Sql
 import flexjson.JSONSerializer;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
 System.out.println("Arrived users");
  JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/test", "root","", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
 def query="select c.id,c.Name, c.Address, c.Department  from people c order by c.id";
  JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
  sql.eachRow(query) {row->
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("id",row.id);
   obj.put("name",row.Name);
    obj.put("address",row.Address);
    obj.put("dept",row.Department);
    json.put(obj);
   }
       out<< json;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! It's for my final project

Comment: `$http.get('getUsers.groovy')` is invalid. You should provide an interface from the backend Groovy code, and get the response from it.

Answer (score 0):

`getUsers.groovy` is not a http URL. Your groovy implementation should map to a web service that returns JSON response. So this  `$http.get('getUsers.groovy')` should be more like `$http.get('http://yourserver/users')`.

On a more general note, anularjs is a client-side technology while groovy is server-side. Checkout [this](http://trishagee.github.io/presentation/angularjs_html5_groovy_java_mongodb_wcpgw/) tutorial for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the tutorial ASAP!! I have tried linking to the file through an http url. Instead of:

`$scope.employees=$http.get('getUsers.groovy').success(function(response){`

I used:

`$scope.employees=$http.get('http://localhost:8080/groovy/final2/getUsers.groovy').success(function(response){
    return response.data
}`

and I get an error that says:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost8080/groovy/final2/getUsers.groovy. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`